# Can snakemake send two rules to the same cluster slot?

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing, snakemake

For reference I am using Sun Grid Engine to run my snakemake pipeline.
A typical line to initiate would be:
`snakemake --cluster "qsub -l mfree=8G -l h_rt=72:0:0" --jobs 20`

This will submit 20 jobs simultaneously, where each job contains one rule and is sent to one slot.
However, my cluster node topology enables SMT, where each slot contains a CPU with 2 threads.
So my goal is to utilize both of these threads by running an independent snakemake rule on each thread. (The rules themselves only use one thread at a time)

The snakemake log files for each of these jobs also recognize "Provided cores: 2" - but since only one rule is scheduled per job, only one of these available cores is used at a time.

For additional context, when running this exact snakemake pipeline in a `qlogin` environment where I first set up an interactive session with 20 slots (40 threads) - snakemake recognizes that there are "Provided cores: 40" - and thus 40 rules are able to be run at one time.

So to reiterate, is there a way to send two rules at a time for each job so I can maximize the available resources on my cluster topology?

Thank you

I have tried specifying `--cores 2`, but this has the opposite functionality of what I want. This would request 2 slots (4 threads) per each job/rule and just exemplifies the problem.